# Printing with HDPE plastic

Tags: filament

Just out of curiosity is it possible to print with HDPE?

Would it be easy or hard?

I know they don't make HDPE filament* but I know people with a filament extruder could make some HDPE because it is a common plastic, which means it can be given a second use or something.

*To my knowledge

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, although PE is not the best material to 3D print, as it has very low melting point (HDPE is just over 100°C), it is unpleasantly waxy to the touch and needs specialised paints and glues.

I never tried myself, but I know the [RecycleBot](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:54180) is supposed to be able to use PE waste to produce a filament.

Comment: does it warp easily like ABS?

Comment: @Ljk2000 - According to https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/linear-expansion-coefficients-d_95.html PE has about twice the thermal expansion of ABS, but since the delta between extrusion and room temperatures is half of that of ABS, my educated guess is that it will probably behave similarly.

Comment: That is good to know. I have never printed with ABS so to print with HDPE would be a real learning curve. But since the temperature is so low I am sure it would be easier to keep the area warm enough while it is printing.